# References to nodes in Java linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I need some help understanding how a method works.

I have a basic `Node` class defined like this:

```
class Node {
    Node next = null;
    int data;
    public Node(int d){
        data = d;
    }
}
```

Now I'm looking at how this `deleteDuplicates` method is working. I understand that we are passing through each node iteratively and storing its value in a set. If the value is already in the set, I believe we are setting the previous node's `next` pointer to skip the current node. Here's the method:

```
public static Node deleteDuplicates(Node head){
    Node n = head;
    HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    Node previous = null;
    while(n != null) {
        if (set.contains(n.data)){
            // skip this node
            previous.next = n.next;
        }
        else {
            set.add(n.data);
            previous = n;
        }
        n = n.next;

    }
    return head;
}
```

I'm confused about the variables `previous` and `n`. When we set `previous = n;`, isn't that making them reference the same object? If they reference the same object, one change you make to `n` will be the same in `previous`. So how does the line `previous.next = n.next;` work?

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't  `previous.next = n.next;`  be `previous = n.next;` ?

Comment: @c0der it seems alright as is, but that still wouldn't explain the reference question

Comment: I ask it because it look that this method is wrong. Using 'previous.next' when `previous` is `null` is one example,

Comment: @c0der previous gets assigned before it gets to that if statement

Comment: Sorry my mistake.

Comment: @c0der that's alright, thanks for the input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

read these 2 lines together,

```
previous = n;  
n = n.next;
```

So, once a node is processed, the pointers for previous and n are moved forward. n is next node after previous, thus previous is set to n, and n is moved to its next node, which is n.next

For the deletion part, hope the diagram below helps

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I think this clears things up for me. I was viewing the entire linked list as a single object, when really its a series of objects (which are nodes). So when we change n to the next node, we aren't referencing the same thing anymore. I appreciate the diagram!